# html dropdown list auto print all button

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, printing

I have an html/javascript page with a dropdown list. When the user clicks on one of the drop down list items the map changes and details about the user's choice appears. Currently the user can right-click to print after their choice. How can I create a Print All button that would go through the entire list and print the results of each choice?

```
<script>
function rander() {
    var tempDate = roughs
    //tempDate.length counts the number of routes in "roughs"
    for (var i = 0; i < tempDate.length; i++) {
        if (tempDate[i].RouteID in data) {
            data[tempDate[i].RouteID].push(tempDate[i])
        } else {
            data[tempDate[i].RouteID] = []
            data[tempDate[i].RouteID].push(tempDate[i])
        }
    }


 //      var element = '<select id="mySelectRoute" onchange="GetMap()">'
    var element = '<select id="mySelectRoute" style="font-size:40px;" onchange="GetMap()">'
    for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(data).length; i++) {
        element = element + '<option value="' + i + '">' + data[Object.keys(data)[i]][0].RouteID + ''
    }
    element = element + '</select>'
    document.getElementById("selectID").innerHTML = element
    loadMap()
}
rander()
```

Comment: can u provide the HTML too?

Comment: <body>
     <div id="selectID" style="position:top; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:10px;font-weight:bold;"></div>
 <div id="myMap" style="position:relative;width:800px;height:600px;"></div>
    <div id="routeInfoPanel" style="position:top; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;"></div>
<!-- displays route information below map-->
    <div id="tableID" style="position:top; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:15px;"></div>
</body>

Comment: lol dont put it here, put it in ur question!